# Cannot render my array in React: getting an error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, and having a lot of trouble understanding why this code doesn't work. All I am trying to do is create a list of 5 0's and render them as list elements in my render method, but I'm getting this error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Matrix extends Component {
  state = {
    elements: this.createList()
  };

  render() {
    return;
    <div>
      <ul>{this.state.elements.map(e => <li>{e}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>;
  }
  createList() {
    var myList = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      myList[i] = 0;
    }
    return myList;
  }
}

export default Matrix;
```

Comment: this is just a component. where do you render it?

Comment: also, why are you returning as the very first line of your render function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `render()` method, you're returning immediately instead of returning the JSX :

```
  render() {
    return;
    <div>
      <ul>{this.state.elements.map(e => <li>{e}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>;
  }
```

I assume you meant to return the actual JSX :

```
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <ul>{this.state.elements.map(e => <li>{e}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `;` after return which makes the render return. Remove `;` and make the return and `<div>...` in same line. It should work.

I suggest you integrate ESLint in your editor, it will highlight unreachable code (in your case the `<div>...</div>`) as you type.

Your code will look like this in my editor. Basically its checking for this [rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be work

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Matrix extends Component {
  state = {
    elements: this.createList()
  };

  render() {
    return;
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.elements.map((e, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{e}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
  createList() {
    var myList = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      myList[i] = 0;
    }
    return myList;
  }
}

export default Matrix;
```

Comment: I think your `return;` keeps the same error as author asked

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code block should be like this. Inside your render `return;` throw you the exception as it is returning nothing expected. So you have to make sure you are returning a block by using `return(<div>...</div>);`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Matrix extends Component {
  state = {
    elements: this.createList()
  };

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <ul>{this.state.elements.map(e => <li>{e}</li>)}</ul>
       </div>;
    )
  }
  createList() {
    let myList = [];
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      myList[i] = 0;
    }
    return myList;
  }
}

export default Matrix;
```